Storing a ref in a ref for conditional use?
Here is some context:

There is a child component B using a ref.
There are two components A and A'; parents of B
A does not need to use the ref
A' needs to use the ref

Then I would like to conditionally pass the ref from A to B.
In B, I would do the following so A' can access the ref:
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
if (apiRefParent && apiRefParent.current!==apiRef){
  apiRefParent.current = apiRef;
}

Would this be a good solution according to you?
Do you have other solutions that would be better?

i think you may be overcomplicating things. Could you please add extended example how exactly would you use refs from B in case of A' and A. I thing we can find the way around more idiomatic to react. maybe even get rid of refs.

Thanks for your response @SlavaSobolev! Agree with you :)
I am using MUI data grid https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/api-object/ and using their ref to trigger actions on the grid.
B is a generic component to add abstractions to the grid (persisting layout for example).
In A, I want to use the extended table.
In A', I would like to add buttons that will trigger actions on the grid thanks to the API.

A new question also comes to my mind.
How would we proceed if we want to interact with the grid from component Z, which is far away in the react tree? I would go with the same solution, storing the ref in a lib like jotai or redux. But this seems once again, overcomplicated. Looking forward to learning your way

got it. i think i know what is the right way to do it.

Ok, based on question, and the additional context from the comments, i think the right way would be utilize React context to store a single ref and access it across the application.

Let's create context for DataGrid ref.

grid-ref.tsx:
import {useContext, createContext} from 'react';
import { useGridApiRef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

export const GridApiRefContext = createContext();

export function useMyGridApiRef() {
  return useContext(GridApiRefContext);
}

export function GridApiRefProvider({ children }) {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
  return (
    <GridApiRefContext.Provider value={apiRef}>
      {children}
    </GridApiRefContext.Provider>
  );
}


Lets wrap the page or the part of the app to this context. This will allow any children components to interact with this ref.

some-page.tsx
import { GridApiRefProvider } from "./grid-ref"
import A1Grid from "./A1Grid"
import A2 from "./A2"
import SomeDeeplyNestedComponent from "./SomeDeeplyNestedComponent"

export default function SomePage() {
   return (
     <GridApiRefProvider>
       <A1Grid />
       <A2 />
       <div>
          <Sidebar>
            <SomeDeeplyNestedComponent />
          </Sidebar>
       </div>
     </GridApiRefProvider>
}


Let's say <A1Grid /> will just render a grid. it will only use useMyGridApiRef to pass ref to the grid.

A1Grid.tsx:
import { useMyGridApiRef } from './grid-ref'
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

function A1Grid() {
   const ref = useMyGridApiRef();
   return <DataGrid ref={ref} ... rest props />
}


Then <A2 /> component with buttons will interact with the grid. A2.tsx

import { useMyGridApiRef } from './grid-ref'

export default function A2() {
   const ref = useMyGridApiRef();
   const nextPage = () => {
      ref.current?.setPage(1);
   }
   return (
     <>
       <button onClick={nextPage}>first page</button>
     </>
   )
}


And Same goes to other components, even deeply nested in the tree.

SomeDeeplyNestedComponent.tsx
import { useMyGridApiRef } from './grid-ref'

export default function SomeDeeplyNestedComponent() {
   const ref = useMyGridApiRef();
   console.log(ref.current);
   return (
     <div>       
     </div>
   )
}

As a result you will have unified api to access an instance of a grid ref from anywhere in the page with the grid.

I like this idea. It can also be stored in a state management library instead of the context.
However, there is still one remaining point that is not treated here: the possibility not to declare and pass the ref (in the section 3.)

i'm afraid there is no way around it, if you want to interact  with the particular instance of the grid from the components outside of the grid itself, you had create refinstance outside of the datagrid and pass it explicitly to the grid as prop.
In order to make it work in the way you like, Datagrid should be able to pickup ref from external context by itself.  :(

Thank you very much for your reply and clear responses!
What do you think about the JS part I wrote in the original post? I tried and it seems to work. But I have the feeling that it may entail undesired behaviors

I mean, if this approach works - why not? At least until you run into some issues with it. From architecture standpoint this if(apiRefParent && apiRefParent.current!==apiRef) apiRefParent.current = apiRef Idea of mutating parent ref from children component looks pretty fragile to me. What if it will be accidentally mutated once more outside of B? Second, because this approach not ideomatic to react, you'd have to provide explanation for your colleagues, why it is implmemente this way, and how not to break it accidentally :)

Very fragile indeed! Maybe the best is not to abstract but to divide the components in this case. One component B and one B' requesting the ref from the parent!
